# How to delete another record in same table using after_destroy callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table in below columns

id, user_id, friend_user_id

If A is a friend of B then, I want to insert two records such as
1. user_id: 1, friend_user_id: 2
2. user_id: 2, friend_user_id: 1

I've did this using the after_create callback as below

```
after_create do
        Friend.create(user_id: friend_user_id,friend_user_id: user_id)
    end
```

I want to delete both records, if any one of the record has been deleted.

I've tried the after_destroy callback as below.

```
after_destroy do
        Friend.where(friend_user_id: user_id,user_id: friend_user_id).first.destroy
    end
```

But I'm getting the below error.

```
2.3.0 :002 > Friend.first.destroy
  Friend Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "friends".* FROM "friends"  ORDER BY "friends"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
  Friend Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."friend_user_id" = ? AND "friends"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "friends"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["friend_user_id", 1], ["user_id", 2]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."id" = ?  [["id", 11]]
  Friend Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."friend_user_id" = ? AND "friends"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "friends"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["friend_user_id", 2], ["user_id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/friend.rb:39:in `block in <class:Friend>'
```

I'm new to RoR. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your call_back is executing after you delete your records, so in between your deletion and callback method, you have nil values. That is why, It is giving you this error

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite wrong here, you will end up getting SystemStackError and that happens in both the places in after_create and after_destroy. What is happening is that when you destroy an element, then your after_destroy callback is executed which will again destroy an element and since it has deleted an element it will again execute a callback, but since you have deleted that element that is why you are getting this error `NoMethodError: undefined method`destroy' for nil:NilClass` because that element has already been deleted, to get a more clear picture use the same code and do a Friend.create and you will see what I am saying.